# how can i get correlationId?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

On my project(spring-rabbit..), Set fixed ReplyTo queue on template, I use convertSendAndReceive method for RPCs.

I understand that mekes correlationId automatically.

**Can I set correlationId before using that method?**

Here is Template.

```
@Bean   
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());       
    template.setRoutingKey(AmqpConstants.JOB_QUEUE_NAME);
    template.setExchange(AmqpConstants.JOB_EXCHANGE_NAME);
    template.setQueue(AmqpConstants.JOB_QUEUE_NAME);    
    template.setReplyQueue(new Queue(AmqpConstants.JOB_REPORT_QUEUE_NAME)); 

    template.setReplyTimeout(replyTimeoutMilliseoconds);

    return template;
}
```

Code

```
jobReport = (ApiJobReport)rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(
                AmqpConstants.JOB_EXCHANGE_NAME, 
                AmqpConstants.JOB_QUEUE_NAME, 
                jobMessage, new MessagePostProcessor() {

                    @Override
                    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
                        message.getMessageProperties().setCorrelationId("correlationid1234".getBytes());
                        return message;
                    }
                });
```

In postProcessMessage, setting correlationId as "correlationid1234".
But RabbitMQ Management shows below.

Message properties :

**correlation_id:   23316fe6-0c15-46f6-9bed-5f3abf22a594**

priority:   0
delivery_mode:  2
headers:
**TypeId**: com.example.model.apijob
content_encoding:   UTF-8
content_type:   application/json

As shown result, set correlationId has changed to RabbitTemplate messageTag value(UUID). Im watching RabbitTemplate source but I dont understand why it makes change to correlationId if correlationKey is null.

[RabbitMQ Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNFXN.png)

Comment: correlationId ? Where is it? Where is your code?

Comment: As I said in my answer below, the template doesn't rely on a user-supplied `correlationId` because it must be unique - so it saves yours off, uses its own to correlate the reply, then restores your `correlationId`. Why do you care that the correlationId is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `sendAndReceive()` (rather then `convertSendAndReceive()`); if you set a correlationId message property, the template saves it off; uses its own correlationId in the outbound message and restores the original correlationId in the reply message.

It's not clear what you mean in the context of `convertSendAndReceive()`; you can't set the correlationId before you call it because there is no message until the conversion takes place.

You could set it in a `MessagePostProcessor` but it won't achieve very much.

Perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to do, I can make some other suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just I was curious how producer can save its correlationId to db. On my project, it may be needed to another producer reply to queue not a Consumer. No problem, If consumer save the correlationId. Your answer is very helpful.