# Spring AMQP and CorrelationId

Tags: spring, spring-amqp

I’ve seen that Spring AMQP changes the value of the property correlationId when you use the method `sendAndReceive()`([how can i get correlationId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053098/how-can-i-get-correlationid)).

If I want to set my own correlationId (I need to save the correlationId before the message is sent), is there any way to prevent spring change the value of the correlationId?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following only applies if you are using a reply-container; if not, Spring doesn't use the correlationId at all.

The template can't rely on a user-supplied `correlationId` because it must be unique and there's no guarantee that a use-supplied one will be.

By default, the template uses the standard `correlationId` header, it saves off any user supplied value internally and restores it when the reply is received. The user-supplied correlationId is not sent to the remote system.

You can tell the template to use a different header for correlation (and leaving the user-supplied value unchanged) by setting the `correlationKey` (e.g. to `springCorrelationId`). However, when doing so, the remote system must echo that header back in the reply (so the template can match the reply to the request).

Comment: Thanks Gary. So there is no possibility of knowing the correlationId before the message is sent?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to access it, but first can you explain what you are trying to achieve (i.e. what you need it for), so I can understand the objective, in case it's something we should consider baking into the framework.

Comment: Of course. The scenario is as follows: When I send a message to the server, it responds (synchronously) with an ACK indicating that the message has been received. After a certain time, it is the server that sends an AMQP message indicating the result of message processing. In both messages, the server sends the correlationId that our client sent to identify the message to which it responds.

Comment: Hmmm -  the `sendAndReceive()` methods only expect one response. Does the ack come back on some other queue? I presume so. One solution would be to add a `MessagePostProcessor` to the template's `beforePublishPostProcessors` - it will be called immediately before the publish - after the correlationId is set up. For long-running requests, however, you might be better off using `send()` and set up a message listener container to receive the replies (and acks); that way you wouldn't tie up the calling thread for all that time.

Comment: Thanks. I have two different queues, one for the ACK and another one for the second message, with another SimpleMessageListenerContainer.